# Require help for setting UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in iphone application

Tags: iphone, multithreading

My iphone application can run on devices with iOS 4 & greater + multithreading & camera is optional (since I can use photo library). I am using GCD for multithreading. Which keys should I mention in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities so that my app will run on only iphone 4, 4S , ipod touch 4g & all ipad ?

If I set front-facing-camera then 1st gen ipad are omitted.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I want to run my application on iphone 3GS,4,4S ,ipod touch 4g & all ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3-

All the details are available about the keys and their availability in iOS. Depending on the lowest iOS version you can pick up keys, those will be automatically supported by their latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I referred the above doc already but I can not manage to decide which keys should I set so that my app will run on iphone 4, 4S,ipod touch 4g & all ipad. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: if you want run on above devices, then i am supposing that at least all of these devices will be minimum of iOS 3.2, so you can use all that keys which are for iOS 3.2 or higher as per your need.

Comment: Please see my EDIT. I forgot to mention iphone 3GS. Also if I set minimum to ios 3.2 , what about GCD?

Comment: Also does apple accept my application if my app doesn't work on ipad 1st gen if set front-facing-camera key?

Comment: there are a lot of app present on app store which support only iPad 2nd Gen. So this is not a criteria for rejection of app. Like you can check for this app - http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/B